# Problems adding a marker on a line graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I'm a newbie in plotting graphs with matplotlib. I'm trying to add a point to represent a mark (beginning of covid-19 vaccination in the UK) in a time-series graph. When I add a point, the y-axis values of my graph only reference the point and I need to see all values. Could someone help me?
This it's my code:

```
twitter_df=pd.read_csv('datasets/covidvaccine_hashtag.csv', low_memory=False)
twitter_data=pd.to_datetime(twitter_df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
df = (pd.to_datetime(twitter_data.dropna())
   .dt.floor('d')
   .value_counts()
   .rename_axis('date')
   .reset_index(name='count'))
df=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='1M')).sum().reset_index()
df=df.sort_values(by='date')
#Adding a mark in a time-series graph
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime('2020-12-25', format='%Y-%m-%d'), '5000', '.')

plt.plot(df['date'],df['count'], c='orange')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Number of interactions')
plt.title('Evolution of interactions with hashtag #CovidVaccine on Twitter')
plt.show()
```

This code produces this graph:[Time-series interactions with #CovidVaccine on Twitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVm0f.png)

I already tried to use subplots but I got the same result

Comment: Try `5000` as a number, not as a string: `plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(...), 5000, '.')`

Comment: Thank you! This solve the problem